# Custom implementing like button in ASP .NET CORE with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Hy everyone,

sorry if my question is duplicate of some, but i didn't found solution for my problem.

However, i'm trying to implement custom like button for posts in my asp.net core mvc application and everything works fine, except when i click on like button, it changes color (like on facebook, blue color etc.) not just for current logged user, but for all logged users. But when other users refresh window, everything is back to normal...

What I want is, when I click on "like" button, to update "like counter" FOR EVERYONE and to change color JUST FOR ME (when I came back some other day, that I know that I liked that post.)

Does someone know how to acomplish this?
Here's my code

Index.cshtml

```
@using Fitness_Centar.Data
@using Fitness_Centar.Data.Models
@using Fitness_Centar.Web.Areas.ModulClan.ViewModels
@using Fitness_Centar.Web.Helper
@model List<TimelineVM>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    MyContext _ctx = (MyContext)ViewData["_ctx"];

User u = Context.GetLoggedUser();
int userId = -1;
if (u.Coach != null)
{
    userId = u.Coach.CoachId;
}
if (u.Employee != null)
{
    userId = u.Employee.EmployeeId;
}
if (u.Member != null)
{
    userId = u.Member.MemberId;
}
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <div class="box box-info custom aktivnosti">
        <div class="box-header with-border padding-l-25">
            <h3 class="box-title">Activities</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="box-body">
            @foreach (var p in Model)
            {
                <div id="@p.Post.PostClanovaId" class="post">
                    <div class="user-info">
                        <img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="~/AdminLTE/dist/img/avatar5.png" />
                        <div class="desc">
                            <span class="username">@p.Post.User.Name @p.Post.User.LastName</span>
                            <span class="post-description">Published: @p.Post.PostDate</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content text-justify">
                        <p>@p.Post.Content</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-footer">
                        @{int n = p.Post.PostId + 1594;}
                        @{
                            var c = _ctx.Likes.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.PostId == p.Post.PostId).FirstOrDefault();

                            if (c != null && c.UserId == userId)
                            {
                                <a href="" id="post-@n" class="likeButton link-black liked" data-postid="@p.Post.PostId" data-userid="@userId">
                                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5"></i>
                                    Like
                                </a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <a href="" id="post-@n" class="likeButton link-black" data-postid="@p.Post.PostId" data-userid="@userId">
                                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5"></i>
                                    Like
                                </a>
                            }
                        }
                        <div class="num-of-likes" id="post-@n-numOfLikes">
                            @p.Likes.Count()
                            <span class="usersThatLiked">
                                @{
                                    string g = "";
                                    foreach (var l in p.Likes)
                                    {
                                        g += l.User.Ime + " " + l.Clan.Prezime;
                                    }
                                    @g;
                                }
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment pull-right">
                            <a href="#" class="link-black">
                                <i class="fa fa-comments-o margin-r-5"></i>
                                Comments
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Komentiraj...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript.js

```
"use strict";
var $connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/ModulClan/Helper/LajkHub").build();

$(".likeButton").prop("disabled", true);

$connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (numOfLikes, postId) {
    var x = postId + 1594;
    var s = "#post-" + x;
    if ($(s).hasClass("liked")) {
        $(s).removeClass("liked");
    } else {
        $(s).addClass("liked");
    }
    $(s + "-num-of-likes").text(numOfLikes);
});

$connection.start().then(function () {
    $(".likeButton").prop("disabled", false);
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});


$(".likeButton").bind("click", function (event) {
    var userId = $(this).attr("data-userid");
    var postId = $(this).attr("data-postid");    

    $connection.invoke("SetLike", userId, postId).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

LikeHub.cs

```
public class LikeHub : Hub
{
    private readonly MyContext _ctx;
    public LikeHub (MyContext context)
    {
        _ctx = context;
    }

    public async Task SetLike(int userId, int postId)
    {
        Likes l = new Likes();
        Likes temp = _ctx.Likes.Where(x => x.PostId == postId && x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

        if(temp != null)
        {
            _ctx.Likes.Remove(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            _ctx.Likes.Add(l);

            l.UserId = userId;
            l.PostId = postId;
        }

        _ctx.SaveChanges();

        int numOfLikes= _ctx.Likes.Where(x => x.PostId == postId).Count();

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", numOfLikes, postId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should retag your question to signalr core and not mvc because the code is mostly signalr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the current user (who clicked the `like button`) via

`var userId = $(this).attr("data-userid");` (as you did when someone clicks the `like button`).

But the problem is this, you are not checking for the `userId` when the `SetLike` is succeeded (inside the `on ReceiveMessage` javascript function).

so to solve this you need to send the `userId` of the user who clicked the `like button` from the backend to the frontend (to the `on("ReceiveMessage"..)` function)

e.g.: `await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", numOfLikes, postId, userId);`

and on the `ReciveMessage` check if the `userId` you got from the backend match the current user who's browsing by `var currentUserId = $(this).attr("data-userid");`

if they are equal then color the `like button`, otherwise just update the `like counter`.

this way would solve your issue.

---

Another solution would be to send 2 requests one is specific for the user who clicked the `like button` and the other is to everyone to update `the like counter`.

Comment: Thank you Hameed for your answer. I updated my code and now it works fine :D

Comment: No problem, I am glad i helped! :D